# How can I pass a socket as an argument to a function being called within a thread?

Tags: rust

I'm going to have multiple functions that all need access to one main socket.

Would it better to:

1. Pass this socket to each function that needs access to it
2. Have a globally accessible socket

Can someone provide an example of the best way to do this?

I come from a Python/Nim background where things like this are easily done.

**Edit:**
How can I pass a socket as an arg to a function being called within a thread.
Ex.

```
fn main() {
   let mut s = BufferedStream::new((TcpStream::connect(server).unwrap()));
   let thread = Thread::spawn(move || {
       func1(s, arg1, arg2);
   });

   while true {
       func2(s, arg1);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Answer for updated question

We can use [`TcpStream::try_clone`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#method.try_clone):

```
use std::io::Read;
use std::net::{TcpStream, Shutdown};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:34254").unwrap();
    let stream2 = stream.try_clone().unwrap();

    let _t = thread::spawn(move || {
        // close this stream after one second
        thread::sleep_ms(1000);
        stream2.shutdown(Shutdown::Read).unwrap();
    });

    // wait for some data, will get canceled after one second
    let mut buf = [0];
    stream.read(&mut buf).unwrap();
}
```

## Original answer

It's usually (let's say 99.9% of the time) a bad idea to have *any* global mutable state, if you can help it. Just do as you said: pass the socket to the functions that need it.

```
use std::io::{self, Write};
use std::net::TcpStream;

fn send_name(stream: &mut TcpStream) -> io::Result<()> {
    stream.write(&[42])?;
    Ok(())
}

fn send_number(stream: &mut TcpStream) -> io::Result<()> {
    stream.write(&[1, 2, 3])?;
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:31337").unwrap();

    let r = send_name(&mut stream).and_then(|_| send_number(&mut stream));

    match r {
        Ok(..) => println!("Yay, sent!"),
        Err(e) => println!("Boom! {}", e),
    }
}
```

You could also pass the `TcpStream` to a struct that manages it, and thus gives you a place to put similar methods.

```
use std::io::{self, Write};
use std::net::TcpStream;

struct GameService {
    stream: TcpStream,
}

impl GameService {
    fn send_name(&mut self) -> io::Result<()> {
        self.stream.write(&[42])?;
        Ok(())
    }

    fn send_number(&mut self) -> io::Result<()> {
        self.stream.write(&[1, 2, 3])?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:31337").unwrap();
    let mut service = GameService { stream: stream };

    let r = service.send_name().and_then(|_| service.send_number());

    match r {
        Ok(..) => println!("Yay, sent!"),
        Err(e) => println!("Boom! {}", e),
    }
}
```

None of this is really Rust-specific, these are generally-applicable programming practices.

Comment: Thank you. Now if I may extend upon the question, how would one pass a socket to a function within a thread :)

Comment: @user3746744 I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but I would just `move` the entire socket into the thread at thread creation time. The thread then owns the socket, similar to how the `GameService` struct owns it in the answer. If that doesn't clear it up, you should read the [threads chapter in The Rust Programming Language](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/threads.html) and then ask new clarifying questions, as needed.

Comment: Now that I really think about it I may be able to just use that struct to access the socket from a thread.